# NoUiSlider in angular - bind to array of numbers

Tags: angularjs, nouislider

I'm trying to do editor for array of numbers using NoUiSlider ([Yankovsky directive](https://github.com/Yankovsky/nouislider-angular))

I've managed to create basic functionality but I'm struggling with binding.

I have my array like this:

```
vm.myNumbers = [1, 2, 6];
```

but this directive requires option to be set as whole object:

```
vm.options = {
  start: 3,
  connect: 'lower',
  range: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10
  }
};
```

I'd like to create slider for each element of my array and automatically update it's value, something like on below picture.

[image]

Problem is NoUiSlider directive doesn't have standalone binding for value.

Here is Plunker showing my current code: http://plnkr.co/edit/ljm96tdcGgvwo3Hnayfk?p=preview

Can I bind items from my array but keep rest of options in that options object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to this plunker code... 
http://plnkr.co/edit/4VgDnm
You are binding same `options` to every slider, and hence getting issues.
I have updated your code which may help you.

Comment: I know that every slider binds to same `options`. I didn't knew how to bind each slider to separate options. In Your code You are creating new sliders, but values in bottom panel aren't changing when You move sliders. At start first slider has value 1, and in bottom panel You can see 1 at beginning of array. When I move first slider I'd like that value to change. That's my main problem.

Comment: So at start sliders should have values as in Your Plunker, but after moving sliders values in bottom panel should change.

Comment: It is because it is binded with primitive data type. and hence passing variables by value not by reference. I think you can use event-handlers provided by that directive. Also I dont think there is need to do that bacause you can access variables using `start` prop from `sliderOptions` array of objects

Comment: Now you can check this updated plunk... http://plnkr.co/edit/4VgDnm?p=preview , Also i have added `step = 1` in options config.

Comment: I through that setting `value` at beginning of my code would be fine, thanks for that. This version looks promising. I'll try it in my code. Sadly this directive isn't allowing single value binding.

Comment: I've managed to edit directive to allow binding I want. Here is Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WnxhZLGvssMBKYg6SgUf?p=preview but for now Your answer is best solution. Thanks!

Comment: You did a great job by editing directive. I think your solution is also feasible. Also i think further improvements in that directive will make it fully customisable using options.

Comment: Please edit Your answer to include link to Your latest Plunker :)

Answer (score -1):

I am nouislider-angular author. I added an example solution to your problem http://yankovsky.github.io/nouislider-angular/examples/#/multiple-sliders-binding.

I used $scope.$watchCollection to check if there are any changes in sliders' values:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    return that.slidersOptions.map(function(options) {
        return options.start;
    })
}, function(newValue) {
    that.numbers = newValue;
});
```

Let me know, if it works for you!